# buttonConnectOnClickListener, FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: android, tcp, onclick, android-asynctask, onclicklistener

The Android client runs with no problems on Android 2.2. But in Android 4.2 i need to use AsyncTask, and i dont know how to properly set it up. On button press client should connects to the TCP server. I have tryed it as the code below, but i`m getting FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 error. please can you look at my code! Thanks.

```
    // ----------------------- CONNECTION BUTTON EVENTLISTENER - begin ----------------------------
Button.OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {



class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, AndroidClientActivity> {
@Override
protected AndroidClientActivity doInBackground(String... message) {





    if(!connected){//if not connected yet
    outputText("connecting to Server");
    try {//try to create a socket and outputstream
    socket = new Socket("192.168.1.112",5353);//create a socket
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());//and stream
    outputText("successfully connected");//output the connection status
    changeConnectionStatus(true);//change the connection status
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {//catch and
    outputText(e.getMessage());//display errors
    changeConnectionStatus(false);
    } catch (IOException e) {//catch and
    outputText(e.getMessage());//display errors
    changeConnectionStatus(false);
    }
    }else{
    outputText("disconnecting from Server...");
    try {//try to close the socket
    socket.close();
    outputText("successfully disconnected");
    changeConnectionStatus(false);//change the connection status
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {//catch and
    outputText(e.getMessage());//display errors
    } catch (IOException e) {//catch and
    outputText(e.getMessage());//display errors
    }
    }




    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AndroidClientActivity jh) {



    }}
                new connectTask().execute();            
            }
        };
```

and this is the error i geting;

```
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:709)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12863)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12863)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12863)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12863)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:273)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12863)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6985)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3333)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3189)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:2849)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:2839)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at com.rovercontrollerandroid.AndroidClientActivity.outputText(AndroidClientActivity.java:249)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at com.rovercontrollerandroid.AndroidClientActivity$3$1connectTask.doInBackground(AndroidClientActivity.java:192)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at com.rovercontrollerandroid.AndroidClientActivity$3$1connectTask.doInBackground(AndroidClientActivity.java:1)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-23 23:27:30.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12005):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable when you post on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to access any UI components from `doInBackground(...)` of an `AsyncTask`.

The error is in the logcat **"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."**.

The `doInBackground(...)` method runs on a different thread. If you want to show progress move the code into `onProgressUpdate(...)` and use `publishProgress(...)` from `doInBackground(...)`.

Any other code that needs to access the UI after `doInBackground(...)` is complete should go into `onPostExecute(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

From your logcat, it looks like `outputText()` is a function that does `UI` operations. It appears you want to show progress. Use `publishProgress()` to update the `onProgressUpdate()` method of `AsyncTask`. You can not do `UI` operations in `doInBackground()`

A short example would be

```
 class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, AndroidClientActivity> {
  ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);  //create progress dialog

 @Override
 protected AndroidClientActivity doInBackground(String... message) {
  publishProgress("message to send");  // put this wherever you are trying to show a message while attempting to download
```

then implement

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    progress.setTitle("Trying");
    progress.setMessage(values[0]);  // this will be the value set in `publishProgress() of doINBackground()
    progress.show();
}
```

then call `progress.dismiss()` in `onPostExecute()`